# How to import from one python file to another

Tags: python, windows

I know this question has been asked a million times but for the life of me I just cannot get this.

I have a scripts `setup.py` and `utility_functions.py` within a folder called `utils`.

utility_functions.py:

```
codeql_language_identifiers = {
    'c': 'cpp',
    'c++': 'cpp',
    'c#': 'csharp',
    'go': 'go',
    'java': 'java',
    'kotlin': 'java',
    'javascript': 'javascript',
    'typescript': 'javascript',
    'python': 'python',
    'ruby': 'ruby',
    'swift': 'swift',
}

traced_languages = [
    codeql_language_identifiers['c'],
    codeql_language_identifiers['c++'],
    codeql_language_identifiers['c#'],
    codeql_language_identifiers['go'],
    codeql_language_identifiers['java'],
    codeql_language_identifiers['kotlin'],
    codeql_language_identifiers['swift'],
]
def is_traced_language(lang):
    return lang in traced_languages
```

setup.py:

```
from utility_functions import codeql_language_identifiers, is_traced_language

def run():
    # Here be code
    filter_for_codeql_supported_languages(['test', 'test2'])

def filter_for_codeql_supported_languages(unfiltered_languages_list):
    filtered_languages_list = []
    
    for lang in unfiltered_languages_list:
        if lang in codeql_language_identifiers.keys():
            filtered_languages_list.append(codeql_language_identifiers[lang])
    return filtered_languages_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

I am executing my code on AzureDevOps similar to:

```
E:\vsts\agent1\_work\_tool\Python\3.10.5\x64\python.exe E:\vsts\agent1\_work\1268\appsec-ado\utils\codeql_setup.py
```

On a Linux agent this works fine but on a Windows agent I get:

```
from utility_functions import codeql_language_identifiers, is_traced_language
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utility_functions'
```

Can someone please help. I'm pulling my hair out with this.

Comment: You can try to change the import statement in codeql_setup.py to a relative import: (from .utility_functions import codeql_language_identifiers, is_traced_language). Make sure that the execution context recognizes this as a package (you might need an __init__.py file in the 'utils' directory).

Comment: Though off the point but how come `def run():` is defined before `def filter_for_codeql_supported_languages():` which it makes use of, gets defined?

Comment: @Temi I tried this and got `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package` instead

Comment: Are you comfortable with having the utils folder become a module? Or will you rather have the two scripts as independent scripts just sitting within the same folder?

Comment: Did you add an _ _init_ _.py file in the utils directory?

Comment: @Temi yes but it's blank. Is that OK?

Comment: Yes that's right it should be blank. Same error after adding it?

Comment: Yep: `from .utility_functions import codeql_language_identifiers, is_traced_language
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: I’m still trying to get the context here. If the `utils` folder is a package now by your addition of an `__init__.py` file, then starting an interpreter in the folder where `utils` is located and running `from utils. utility_functions import codeql_language_identifiers, is_traced_language` should work fine because [starting a Python interpreter in the directory, containing the utils package will automatically add the directory to `sys` path.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)

Comment: Sorry, should be from utility_functions import codeql_language_identifiers, is_traced_language. Now that you have the init.py in the same directory it should work

Comment: @Temi It depends on the context. If the interpreter is fed a script, then the directory the script is contained in is [what gets added to `sys.path` as the first element of that list.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) But if the interpreter is started in the parent folder of the `utils` package, then the directory where the `utils` package is contained in is what gets added to `sys.path` so that writing `from utils.utility_functions import •••` is valid since `utils` is now a recognizable package because it’s path has been added to `sys.path`

Comment: @Temi Still getting this error after removing the dot: `No module named utility_functions'`

Comment: You need to understand how [module search works in Python.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#searching) Since you have not been able to explain the context in which you are running your code, I can’t help.

Comment: I have given the exact execution command in my question. What other specific information do you require?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon I feel you

Comment: Weird really, I can imagine how you’re feeling man. Do you have to run the script from the root directory?

Comment: @Temi The script is executed from a yml file: `  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filepath'
    scriptPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/appsec-ado/utils/codeql_setup.py'`

Comment: Would this have anything to do with the PATH or PYTHONPATH environment variables?